# Resteasy with Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, resteasy

I have a working Rest web service that use JBoss Resteasy however when I tried to port it to use GAE I'm getting this error when executing:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used resteasy successfully on GAE.
As csturtz mentioned make sure your project has the resteasy dependency.

If yo uare using Maven this should be something like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

And optionally you also would like to use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-hibernatevalidator-provider</artifactId>
    <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
    <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yes, the resteasy jars is in the "Maven Dependencies" which is in the classpath. Is that what you meant?

Comment: And BTW, I have the dependency in the POM

Answer (score 2):

it would seem you're missing the Resteasy JAR file in your GAE WAR file.  Locate this jar file, add it to your GAE WAR build, and you should be good to go (or at least past this specific error).

Comment: I have the Maven Dependencies which have the Resteasy jar in my application Classpath... what do you mean?

Comment: If you have the resteasy dependencies configured in your maven build, I'd do 2 things.  1) open up your GAE WAR file and MAKE SURE the Resteasy JAR files are in there.  2) Open up the Resteasy JAR files that are included in your WAR and MAKE SURE the class you're getting the error for is actually in one of those jars.  For some reason, GAE can't find that resteasy class so we just need to track down the exact cause.

Answer (score 1):

Is the resteasy jar file in /war/WEB-INF/lib ? It needs to be copied there AND put on your classpath.