# Creating REST-like url mapping for servlets on App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, rest, servlets, web.xml

I would like to create a REST-like url mapping on Google App Engine with Java. The difficulty is that I want to use the following URL mapping:

```
/users -> UserListServlet
/users/4547 -> UserServlet
/users/3422/posts -> PostListOfUserServlet
/users/5433/posts/1234 -> PostOfUserServlet
```

But according to the manual (http://www.roguewave.com/portals/0/products/hydraexpress/docs/3.5.0/html/rwsfservletug/4-3.html), in the web.xml I can only have one wildchar at the end of the URL, so I can map to `/users` and `/users/*`, but I can't map to `/users/*/posts` and `/users/*/posts/*`.

What is the easy and conventional way to separate these cases and get the parameters, are there good practices, or I must create a servlet what gets all `/users/*` requests and then split it at "/" characters and manually pass them to the different servlets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a REST framework like [RESTEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy). [Others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629028/resteasy-with-google-app-engine) have deployed it successfully on GAE.

Other options include [Spring MVC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) and [Restlet](http://restlet.org/).

All of them will abstract away the low level details of the `Servlet` API and let you focus on your services.

Comment: Thanks, I tried RESTEasy, and works greatly with GAE, except this small bug: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1365