# App Engine Endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine, rest, google-cloud-endpoints

Im starting a new application with AppEngine and I need a REST Service.

I was looking at Endpoints and I think they are exactly what I need.
I also read Google don't recommend to use Endpoints in production but my app first version is not going out until April approximately.

How mature do you think App engine Endpoints are?

Do you recommend to use them or should I find another REST framework.

If so, Are there any other REST framework similar to App Engine Endpoints?

or
  Which one do you recommend, Restlet? or use it with Spring MVC?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a bit biased (being a Googler and member of the App Engine team), but I think Endpoints is worth a try. With regards to the general disclaimer on using Endpoints in production, we have allowed some developers to launch in production as long as they have spoken to us first.

I provided another answer to a related question on RESTful development [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453561/restful-service-framework-for-appengine/11680605#11680605). The developer tried Endpoints and decided to use it over other options.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I decide I'll use endpoints. How can I contact you to allow me use them in production?

Comment: If you're ready to use Endpoints in production and the feature is not yet out of TT, send a message to the TT forum and we'll respond.