# How to fetch values from GAE datastore to android application ?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-app-engine

I'm creating a network based android application. So

1) I've installed Google App Engine Plugin in eclipse IDE and start developing a network based android applications where all information of customers are stored in GAE Datastore.

2) I've created a new Web-Application and stored Entities in datastore. Can i retrieve those values and show in my android application and add new details in from my application to GAE Datastore.

Please Help Me, I'm new to Web Service, SOAP, REST, JSON etc.

Can anyone tell me a simple method to store and fetch values from Cloud DB to Android App.

Answer (score 0):

There are two apparent options:

1. [Use Cloud Endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11680605/248432). They are proprietary and not my favourite. Also they are only available for Android, iOS and JS.
2. Use web services, my favourite would be [JAX-RS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services), specifically [RESTEasy](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.7.Final/userguide/html/index.html)+[Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). See this [GAE example](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/integrate-jackson-with-resteasy/) and [simple Android client](https://github.com/drorba/resteasy-mobile).